# How to get ng-repeat checkbox values by row and column from a table

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table comprised mainly of checkboxes. This is a simplistic version of how it looks.

```
Name    |  A |  B |  C |  D |  E |
--------|----|----|----|----|----|
James   | [] | [X]| [] | [] | [] |
--------|----|----|----|----|----|
Micheal | [x]| [] | [] | [] | [] |
--------|----|----|----|----|----|
Peter   | [] | [] | [] | [x]| [] |
--------|----|----|----|----|----|
Eddy    | [] | [] | [] | [] | [] |
--------|----|----|----|----|----|
```

From the table above, there's a names column and A to E columns with checkboxes.
My question is how I can get the the values of the checked checkboxes with the associated name_id of that row. Each column has a distinct id as well. So for instance an object of the above sample could be:

```
{
  table_id:1
  checked_boxes: [
                   {name_id:10, col_id:2},
                   {name_id:20, col_id:1},
                   {name_id:30, col_id:4}
                 ]
}
```

This is my `tbody` with the `ng-repeat`:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in names track by $index">
      <td id="{{item.name_id}}">{{item.name}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="col in cols">
         <input type="checkbox" value="" class="form-control" ng-model="selected[col.col_id]" />
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Do I need to make any adjustments in the `tbody`? And how can I get the desired object shown above specifically the `checked_boxes`? I've tried various means of `push`ing the values into a `checked_boxes` empty array to no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkboxes array is hard to work with. So it's just takes a bit of rearrangement. Start with a 2D array of checkboxes and populate it all with `false` values. Then run through known checkboxes and find their index for rows and columns, then simply show it with `ng-model="checkboxes[$parent.$index][$index]"`.

Here is my version as a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  var n = $scope.names = [
    {name_id:10, name:"Micheal"},
    {name_id:20, name:"James"},
    {name_id:30, name:"Peter"},
    {name_id:40, name:"Eddy"}
  ];
  var c = $scope.cols = [
    {col_id:1},
    {col_id:2},
    {col_id:3},
    {col_id:4},
    {col_id:5}
  ];

  var checked_boxes = [
    {name_id:10, col_id:2},
    {name_id:20, col_id:1},
    {name_id:30, col_id:4}
  ];
  
  $scope.checkboxes = n.map( function(x) {
    return c.map( function(y) { 
      return false;
    });
  })
  
  for(var i=0; i<checked_boxes.length; i++){
    var ni = n.map(function(_) { return _.name_id; }).indexOf(checked_boxes[i].name_id); // match the index of `name_id`
    var ci = checked_boxes[i].col_id-1; // or like above -> c.map(...).indexOf(...) // but for `col_id`
    $scope.checkboxes[ni][ci] = true;
  }
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in names track by $index">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="col in cols">
          <input type="checkbox" value="" class="form-control" ng-model="checkboxes[$parent.$index][$index]" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a little example for you so you can have this simpler. My suggestion is as follows:

- Instead of use `ng-model` on your checkboxes you can change to `ng-click` to set the value on your data array, making it easier if you want to gather this information later.

  ```
  <div ng-app="questions">
       <div  ng-controller="QuestionController as ctrl">
       <table>
           <thead>
             <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>A</th>
              <th>B</th>
              <th>C</th>
              <th>D</th>
              <th>E</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             <tr ng-repeat="item in ctrl.questions track by $index">
                <td id="{{item.name_id}}">{{item.name}}</td>
                  <td ng-repeat="col in ctrl.cols">
                     <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" ng-click="ctrl.selectOption(item, col)"/>
                  </td>
             </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
       <button ng-click="ctrl.load()">
            Load button data
       </button>
       </div>
  </div>
  ```
- And in your javascript you will have the following:

  ```
  angular.module('questions', []);
  angular.module('questions').controller('QuestionController', QuestionController);

  function QuestionController () {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.questions = [{
      name: 'Name 1',
      name_id: 'Name_1',
      selectedOption: ''
    },{
      name: 'Name 2',
      name_id: 'Name_2',
      selectedOption: ''
    },{
      name: 'Name 3',
      name_id: 'Name_3',
      selectedOption: ''
    }];

    ctrl.cols = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

    ctrl.selectOption = function (entry, selectedOption) {
      entry.selectedOption = selectedOption;
    };

    ctrl.load = function () {
      angular.forEach(ctrl.questions, function (question) {
        console.log('Name: ' + question.name + ' - Answer: ' + question.selectedOption);
      });
    }

  }
  ```